# GDI+ Graphics.Clear gives Invalid Parameter error

Tags: gdi+

I can't get even the most basic GDI+ method to work :) It is giving me an Invalid Parameter error. Below is my code, do you see anything wrong?

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;

...

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC         hdc;

        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        Graphics g(hdc);
        Color color = Color::Black;
        Status error = g.Clear(color);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
}
return 0;
}
```

It seems pretty straight forward, but for someone reason nothing clears at all.

I am linking with the gdiplus.lib and UNICODE is defined.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Where is your GdiPlusStartup() call?  Required.

Comment: Thank you! I was not calling that at all. Everything works now :)